# Change order of bar in multiple barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

Hello everyone i want to ask how can i change the order of my multi barplot?
[image]

I want to make the 'Yes' from y axis at top and 'No' from y axis at the bottom.

This is the dataframe:

[image]

This is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.barplot(x=df_3['Jumlah'],y=df_3['Use Phone Service'],hue=df_3['Is Senior Citizen'],
            order=df_3.sort_values('Use Phone Service',ascending=False)
plt.show()
```

I got some weird result like this :
[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: Hi can you please show your dataframe?

Comment: did you try ascending=True

Comment: Yes, it shows the same weird result

Comment: @Stackpy hello, i already edit my post to show my dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to specify the specific column after `.sort_values()` or else it take the whole df as occurred with you, secondary you will need get the unique values or else it will take all values of column in Y axis.

```
plot_order = df_3.sort_values(by='Use Phone Service', ascending=False)['Use Phone Service'].unique()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.barplot(x='Jumlah',y='Use Phone Service',hue='Is Senior Citizen',
            data=df_3,   order=plot_order)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]